# How do I create a link to a pdf file with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a pdf file in my rails app that I would like to create a link for. When the user hits the link I want the pdf to be previewed if it is possible in their browser and if not I want it to be downloaded. I'm pretty sure that if it's a download link to a pdf many browsers will preview it by default but I am not sure.

Comment: did `link_to` or `<a>... </a>` didn't work?

Comment: I wanted to know the "rails way" of doing it. Yes, I could use an <a> tag but it would be better if I used rails and I wasn't sure how to do that.

Comment: is link_to not rails way?

Comment: It is actually, believe it or not

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have your pdf file in `public` directory of the application, you can create link like:

```
<%= link_to "My PDF", asset_path("pdf_file.pdf") %>
```

Comment: hey, is there any step after this? I did this, it worked on the local server but when I deploy it to production, it says "The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved." I'm using rails 5.1.6, thanks.

Comment: @ttinggggg I haven't tested it on Rails 5, however, I think you need to place the asset correctly and skip the pipeline: `asset_path("pdf_file.pdf", skip_pipeline: true)` - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path

Comment: I had to put my PDF in the images file inside app/assets to get this to work, but it worked.